# How to hide SharePoint list columns from users based on permission

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

I need to hide "Approver" add "Title" fields in my SharePoint list. I used the following JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=class="vglnk" 
href="https://...SiteAssets/jquery-
1.10.1.min.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src= class="vglnk" href="https://...SiteAssets/jquery.SPServ
ices-2014.02.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Approver) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

   //If the current User does belong to the group "Test Group"
    if (xml.search('Test Group') == -1)
     {
      //   alert("No, User Doesn't Exists!");                  
       $("select[title=Approver]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
       $("select[title=Title]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
       //or use: $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Status")').parent().hide();
      //You can also use:$('nobr:contains("Status")').closest('tr').hide();
       }  
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And your question is? Is there an error from your JS?

Comment: It doesn't hide. Still exist

Comment: Which version of SharePoint 2013, 2016 or SharePoint Online? And, how did you add the JS to the page?

Comment: Also, what happens when you use $("select[title=Approver]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); from the browser's F12 tools console?

Comment: I used CEWP after I saved on the site asset SP10. Error:(Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined$(document).ready(function() {)

Comment: And I did stop inheritance and gave Test Group Full permission.

Comment: Does typing https://...SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js directly into the browser display an error or start a download? And is you JavaScript code in the Content Editor Web Part, or is in a linked file stored in a library?

Comment: linked file stored in a library?

Comment: "linked file stored in a library?" > The Content Editor Web Part has a habit of striping out, or ignoring JavaScript and CSS tags. The best way to prevent that is to store your code in a text file in a SharePoint library such as Site Assets. I save my linked files with an html extension to make them easy to edit straight from the library using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. You just need to specify with *if*s which permissions requires the users that opens the list.

SPServices `GetGroupCollectionFromUser()` function gets all user's permissions, and in the *if* you just need to:

```
//Example
console.log(xml);
xml = ['Read', 'Contribute'];

//If the current User does NOT belong to the group "Contribute"
if (xml.search('Contribute') != -1){
    $("select[title=Approver]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
    $("select[title=Title]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Jquery and SPService library is loaded in the page correctly and here is the completed code which works:

```
<!-- jQuery Reference. You can refer it from Layouts Folder/Doc Library too, after uploading the script. -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Download SPServices from: http://spservices.codeplex.com/ Or use this CDN  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

   //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
    if (xml.search('Service Desk Operators') == -1)
     {
          //   alert("No, User Doesn't Exists!");                  
           $("select[title=Status]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
          //or use: $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Status")').parent().hide();
          //You can also use:  $('nobr:contains("Status")').closest('tr').hide();
       }  
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the code that you attached. But, It doesn't hide the column.

Comment: Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:28
(anonymous) @ VM252:1