# Set list column permission in different views of the same list - sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, list-view, column

In sharepoint 2016 I have a list with several views each targeting different audience. I need some solution to manage column permission in new/edit/display forms. I tried https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sp2013columnpermission but I could not download the wsp file described (download gets .git folder which can not fetch any branches: not found). 
Why sharepoint has some easy solution to render target audience to list views but has no out-of the box solution for managing the list forms of these views?
Do you have any idea how to get it?
I tried also jquery like: [How to hide SharePoint list columns from users based on permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234773/how-to-hide-sharepoint-list-columns-from-users-based-on-permission?rq=1)
but simply did not hide the column (jquery was loaded).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample tested script, while you need update the jQuery selector based on your filed type and group title.`$("input[title='testNumber']")` just select single line text filed title as testNumber.

```
<!-- jQuery Reference. You can refer it from Layouts Folder/Doc Library too, after uploading the script. -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Download SPServices from: http://spservices.codeplex.com/ Or use this CDN  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
                userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
                async: false,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var _PerCheck = false;
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Group").each(function () {
                        var currentGroup = $(this).attr("Name");                        
                        if (currentGroup == 'Developer Owners') {
                            _PerCheck = true;
                        }                        
                    })
                    if (!_PerCheck) {
                        $("input[title='testNumber']").closest('tr').hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Lee_MSFT! You code works if I change to " if (_PerCheck) { " but only in Edit/New list forms. Unfortunatelly it does not hide the field in the Display form (view item). Do you have any ideas how to hide it? And how can I make field to show "Read only" in New/Edit form?

Comment: The control display as different html in display form, for display form, use $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("testNumber")').closest('tr').hide();

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hide column in New/Edit listform, this code works for me in scripteditor:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/mysite/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/mysite/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript">        $(document).ready(function () {            $().SPServices({                operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",                userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),                async: false,                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {                    var _PerCheck = false;                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Group").each(function () {                        var currentGroup = $(this).attr("Name");                                                if (currentGroup == 'GroupName') {                            _PerCheck = true;                        }                                            })                    if (_PerCheck) {                                              $("input[title='Status']").parent().parent().parent().hide();                     }                }            });        });    </script>
```

For DisplayForm I used this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/mysite/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/mysite/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">        $(document).ready(function () {            $().SPServices({                operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",                userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),                async: false,                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {                    var _PerCheck = false;                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Group").each(function () {                        var currentGroup = $(this).attr("Name");                                                                      if (currentGroup == 'GroupName') {                            _PerCheck = true;                        }                                            })                    if (_PerCheck) {                        $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Status")').parent().hide();                    }                }            });        });    </script>
```

Read-only column: I created a new calculated column referencing the required one.

Thank You!